# "From A to Z" and other corresponding prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Certain prepositional phrases seem to correspond to each other in the same way that correlative conjunctions do, but I've never heard of any grammar that relates two PPs.

```
He traveled from France to Germany.
```

Are "from France" and "to Germany" really independent phrases? Saying "He traveled from France." doesn't sound complete.

Comment: "Twelve international students converged on New York City for a special event being held at the United Nations. Bjork travelled from Sweden. Esteban travelled from Spain. Rodolfo travelled from Italy. Stavros travelled from Greece . . .." The sentences are not elegant, but they sound complete, yes?

Comment: Or even Q: "Where did he travel from?"  A:"He travelled from France".

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question a year ago and I've concluded that 'to' completes the meaning of 'from'.

```
... took care of him from cradle to grave
... went from poverty to fortune
... everything from A to Z
... flew from Canada to Mexico
```

Analyzing it as a single constituent instead of two separate PPs acting independently simplifies things. I'm calling 'from-to' a *correlative preposition* that describes movement between an origin and a destination and functions as an adjunct or complement of verbs and nouns.

Yes, I made that up, but there's no other reasonable way to analyze it.

```
Walmart sells everything from garden tools to household appliances.
```

In this sentence you see that from and to cannot be independent PPs.

You can't reverse their order:

```
everything to household appliances from garden tools
```

You also can't leave one out:

```
everything from garden tools.
```

From-to is a constituent, a two-part PP that's functioning as a complement of everything.

Comment: You might be better leaving them as separate PPs. John went from Aachen to Crewe via Brobdingnag / John went from Aachen via Brobdingnag to Crewe.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth They can function as separate PPs but when used together they complement each other - it's exactly analogous to correlative conjunctions.

Comment: No it's not. *He not only ate some bacon. (as a stand-alone statement) / *Either John was asleep. / *Both Ted was there. / *Neither the left-hand track will get you there. You can't replace 'Either John or Paul' with 'Either John', etc, as you can replace 'flew from Heathrow to Paris' with 'flew from Heathrow'. // Note that 'from cradle to grave' is a fixed expression; the expected articles are usually dropped. There are quite a few 'from A to B' idioms (snowclones). But the PPs are otherwise neighbourwise quite promiscuous: 'He sailed from Southampton across the Atlantic' / ..

Comment: 'walked from Tibet over the Himalayas' / 'ran from him round the corner' / 'rolled from her lap under the table' / 'he went from them out of the camp' ....// As rhetorician says, the 'to-phrases' are hardly mandatory (and so some would say cannot be termed 'complements'), though they do often make the constructions sound somewhat more natural. But English is full of such things: try substituting 'sad' for 'dejected' in 'Dejected / Inconsolable, he decided not to leave his room that day.' The length of the adjective used in the absolute construction seems critical.

Comment: Note also that the non-idiom ones in your examples *are* reversible: *flew to Mexico from Canada* is perfectly fine (even though it changes the emphasis). I'd say there's two cases, really: when *from* and *to* specify origin and destination, they are independent; but when they describe a complete interval (from A to Z and everything in between, from cradle to grave and everything in between), the order becomes fixed, reflecting the order of the interval.

Comment: ...from servitude to magnitude

Answer (score 0):

I see the expression **He travelled from France to Germany** as a compound sentence comprising two separate clauses joined by from-to( which serves as conjunction)... One could say he travelled from France (here only the takeoff point is considered noteworthy). He travelled to Germany( here only the destination is considered important. So. HE TRAVELLED FROM FRANCE TO GERMANY is a combination of the two clauses. Therefore, in my opinion, from-to is acting as an ad-hoc or improvised conjunction. Also, I don't think **from France** and **to Germany** are prepositional phrases...they sound more adverbial as they modify the verb **travelled** by stating **place**. Once again, this is just my opinion, no citations available. Cheers.

Comment: Prepositional phrases can function as verb adjuncts (*went to France*), or as noun adjuncts (*ambassador to France*): one does not preclude the other. *France Germany* which you propose as a "second clause" is not a clause. "from-to" is not conjunction just because it gives two independent pieces of information about the same event (origin and destination), no more than "by-at" is a conjunction in *I came by bus at noon*.